# How to run automation tests on AppCenter specific to Android and iOS only?

Tags: visual-studio-app-center, xamarin.uitest

I am using Xamarin.UITest and NUnit to automate mobile applications and am making use of an Azure DevOps pipeline to run the tests on AppCenter. The tests are currently running fine on both Android and iOS platforms on AppCenter. However, I have a requirement where I would like to run specific tests only on Android and rest only on iOS. Can anyone please share some suggestions on how to make this happen?

Comment: Why don't you just add a check for `Device.RuntimePlatform`, as shown here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/device and if it equals `Device.iOS`, just do a return in your setup?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution by myself. I made it work by checking the platform before each test in the Setup method. Please find my below code written in C# and NUnit.
For instance, there are 2 tests in which only one test should run and another should not run, then have one test(need to run) with category labeled iOS and another with no category.

```
[TextFixture(Platform.Android)]
[TextFixture(Platform.iOS)]
public class Sample{
       [SetUp]
        public void RunBeforeEachTest()
        {
            if(AppManager.Platform == Platform.iOS)
            {
                if(!hasiOSCategory())
                {
                    Assert.Inconclusive();
                }
            }
        }
```

Then perform a check in the setup method to verify whether the current platform is iOS and also check the test has iOS category

```
// this method is used to get all categories of the test.
        private static bool hasiOSCategory()
        {   
            var categories = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test?.Properties["Category"];
            bool hasTestContainsiOSCategory = categories != null && categories.Contains(Constant.iOS);
            return hasTestContainsiOSCategory;
        }

        [Test,Category("iOS")]
        public void TestWithCategory()
        {
            \\your code
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestWithoutCategory()
        {
        }
}
```

Finally, one thing if anything is possible to achieve in the framework then it should work on AppCenter as well.